# common lisp で OCaml 風の書き方をしたい。

Tags: common-lisp

common lisp初心者なのですが、誰か教えていただけないでしょうか。

CLISPで、Ocamlのように再帰関数を同一の関数名でラップしたい場合、どのようにするべきでしょうか。
たとえば、以下のreverseのような例です。

```
let rec reverse xs ys =
    match xs with
    | [] -> ys
    | x::xs -> reverse xs (x::ys);;
let reverse xs = reverse xs [];;
```

この問題を解決しようと思い、自分でマクロを書いてみました。

```
(defconstant else t)

(defmacro defun* (sym bindings &body body)
  (let ((temp (gensym))
        (rest (gensym)))
    `(setf (symbol-function ',sym)
           (function
            (lambda ,bindings
             (let ((,temp (symbol-function ',sym)))
               (flet ((,sym (&rest ,rest)
                        (apply ,temp ,rest)))
                 ,@body)))))))

(defun my-reverse (xs ys)
  (cond ((null xs) ys)
        (else
         (my-reverse (cdr xs) (cons (car xs) ys)))))


(defun* my-reverse (xs)
  (my-reverse xs (list)))
```

しかし、これをSBCLで評価しようとするとエラーが出てしまいます。

```
* (my-reverse '(1 2 3))

debugger invoked on a SB-INT:SIMPLE-PROGRAM-ERROR:
  invalid number of arguments: 2
```

解決策を教えていただけませんでしょうか。

Answer (score 4):

Common Lispには、let recに相当するものとして、labelsがありますので、それを使えば、
ほぼそのまま書けるので、定義用のマクロを書く必要はないと思います。

下記では、パターンマッチにoptimaを使用しています。

```
(ql:quickload :optima)


;;; a
(defun rev (xs)
  (labels ((rev (xs ys)
             (optima:match xs
               ('() ys)
               ((cons x xs) (rev xs (cons x ys))))))
    (rev xs '() )))


;;; b
(labels ((rev (xs ys)
           (optima:match xs
             ('() ys)
             ((cons x xs) (rev xs (cons x ys))))))
  (defun rev (xs)
    (rev xs '() )))


(rev '(0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9))
;=>  (9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 0)
```

bの方が元のプログラムに形は似ていますが、aの方がCommon Lisp的には最適化面で都合が良いです。

元のプログラムが動かない理由ですが、大域のmy-reverse関数は一つしか引数を取らないところに2つ引数を与えているからです。

定義されているdefun*については、何が悪いのか、Common Lispの基本的な仕組みと使っている関数の仕様をもう一度確認してみると良いのではないでしょうか。

また、スタイル的な問題ですが、

```
(defconstant else t)
```

はelseが(同一パッケージ内で)束縛変数名として使えなくなってしまうので、良くありません。

```
(Defmacro myif (pred then &Optional else)
  ...)
```

のようなマクロを書いて謎のエラーに悩んだりする羽目になります。

```
(cond ((...))
      (:else ...));or 'else
```

位で妥協するのが良いかなと思います。

Comment: ご指摘ありがとうございます。
なるほど!
labelsはInnner Function用だと思い込んでいたので、TopLevelで使うという考えが浮かびませんでした。
確かにlabelsをTopLevelで使えば、(b)のように書けますね。
ありがとうございます。

(a)が効率の良い書き方だそうですが、
labelsを使うと、ネストが深くなってしまい、読みにくくなってしまうのが、少しいやだったりします。くわえて、Innner FunctionだけREPLでテストしたい、という時もありますし。そういう場合、やはり、再帰関数とそれをラップする関数とで関数名を変えるしかないんでしょうね。

少し話は変わりますが、Common lispのdefunは、Ocamlのlet recに相当するものですが、OCamlのletに相当するlispの関数定義の方法は存在しないのでしょうか？

Comment: let rec / let に似ている関係としては、labels / fletがあります。

しかし似ているだけで同じものではないと思います。

同様にdefunとlet recは似てはいますが、同じものではないため、質問の範囲を限定しないと、何をもって『相当するもの』なのか限定できないかなと思います。

別途新規の質問に分けてみてはどうでしょうか。

Answer (score 4):

そうですね、、、再帰関数を同一の関数名でラップするのではなくて、optional argument を使ってみてはいかがでしょうか。

```
(defun my-reverse (xs &optional ys)
  (cond ((null xs) ys)
        (t (my-reverse (cdr xs) (cons (car xs) ys)))))

(my-reverse '(1 2 3))
=> (3 2 1)
```

Comment: なるほど!
Optional argumentsについてすっかり忘れていました。
ありがとうございます。

Answer (score 1):

`defun*` マクロですが、以下の様に書いてみました。

```
(defmacro defun* (sym bindings &body body)
  (let ((my_pkg "MY-FUNCTIONS"))
    `(progn
       (or (find-package ,my_pkg)
           (make-package ,my_pkg :use '(common-lisp)))
       (setf (symbol-function
              (intern (string ',sym) ,my_pkg))
             (symbol-function ',sym))
       (unintern ',sym)
       (setf (symbol-function (intern (string ',sym)))
             (lambda ,bindings
               (let ((*package* (find-package ,my_pkg)))
                 ,@body))))))
```

別パッケージ(MY-FUNCTIONS)を作成して、そちらに元の関数と同名のシンボルを作成して関数バインディングを退避させています。

```
(defun my-reverse (xs ys)
  (cond ((null xs) ys)
        (t (my-reverse (cdr xs) (cons (car xs) ys)))))

(defun* my-reverse (xs) (my-reverse xs '()))

(my-reverse '(1 2 3 4 5))
=> (5 4 3 2 1)
```

この `defun*` マクロは SBCL 1.0.50 では動作しますが、他の Common Lisp 処理系では動かないかもしれません。

Comment: 横道に逸れている気がしますが、気になったのでコメントです。
上記のdefun*はいくつかの点で問題があります。

    (setf (fdefinition 'fib)
          (labels ((fib (n)
                     (if (< n 2)
                         n
                         (+ (fib (1- n))
                            (fib (- n 2))))))
            #'fib))
どうしてもその書法にこだわりたい場合、labelsを使えば書けます。

Comment: はい、無粋な事は承知の上で試してみました。個人的に、この様な題材にはなかなかお目にかかれませんので。。。これを機会に Emacs Lisp にある advice-add か defadvice を Common Lisp に移植してみようかと目論んでいます(CLOSは使わずに)。

Answer (score 1):

defun*を書き直してみました。

無理矢理感が拭えないですが、一応、動いてくれています。

```
(defmacro defun+ (funsym bindings &body body)
  `(defun ,funsym ,bindings
     (labels ((,funsym ,bindings ,@body))
       ,(cons funsym bindings))))

(defmacro defun* (funsym bindings &body body)
  (let ((temp (gensym))
        (fexist (fboundp funsym)))
    `(progn
       (when ,fexist
         (setf (symbol-function ',temp)
               (symbol-function ',funsym)))
       (defun ,funsym ,bindings
         (if ,fexist
             (flet ((,funsym (&rest rest)
                      (apply #',temp rest)))
               (progn ,@body))
             (progn ,@body))))))


(defun+ my-reverse (xs ys)
  (cond ((null xs) ys)
        (:else
         (my-reverse (cdr xs) (cons (car xs) ys)))))

(defun* my-reverse (xs)
    (my-reverse xs (list)))
```